# remove custom validation dynamic into Angular 2

Tags: angular, validation

> i want set input required if checkbox is checked. validation working
>   fine but  when i uncheck checkbox at that time i remove required
>   validation. but form not valid and save button not enabled.

**here my formbuilder.**

```
this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group(
                {
                    has_not_visited_in_days_group: this.formBuilder.group({
                        has_not_visited_in_days: [false],
                        has_not_visited_in_days_input: [''],
                    }, {validator: this.requiredIfHasNotVisitedChecked}),
                 });
```

**here custom validator function**

```
requiredIfHasNotVisitedChecked(control: AbstractControl): void {
        const input = control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').value;
        const inputCheckbox = control.get('has_not_visited_in_days').value;
        control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').setValidators([]);
        if (inputCheckbox) {
            if (input === '' || input === null) {
                control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').setValidators([Validators.required]);
            }else {
                control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').setValidators([]);
            }
        }else{
            control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').setValidators([]);
        }
    }
```

**also i tried**

```
  control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').setValidators(null);
```

***Thanks in advance. have any idea please help me.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: false, emitEvent: false});`

Here's its signature:

```
updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
}): void;
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TLua6wQcuhoZiDWBAuBe?p=preview)

**UPDATE**:

This was not the case, what we did in the plunk together was eventually subscribe to the change events of the checkbox, and accordingly disable/enable the input field (leave the required validator on it, it'll be excluded from validation if it's disabled which is better than removing validators).

Comment: Just call `control.get('has_not_visited_in_days_input').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: false});`

Comment: Maybe something else is still invalid?

Comment: once i add value into input and  uncheck then form is valid

Comment: Maybe post a plunk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146413/discussion-between-shailesh-ladumor-and-amit).

Answer (score 6):

I don't see that you'd need the custom validator, you could just rely on a simple change-event:

Here I like to shorten the form controls in component by using variables, so that they are easier to work with, since property paths can get very long. Here are the two controls:

```ts
this.inputCtrl = this.filterForm.get('has_not_visited_in_days_group.has_not_visited_in_days_input')
this.checkboxCtrl = this.filterForm.get('has_not_visited_in_days_group.has_not_visited_in_days')
```

and then the change event for the checkbox:

```html
<input (change)="check(checkboxCtrl.value)" type="checkbox" formControlName="has_not_visited_in_days"/>
```

And just like mentioned by Amit, you'd need to update the value and validity of the form control. Here's that and the function that checks the state of the checkbox and updates the validator accordingly:

```ts
check(bool) {
  if (bool) { 
    this.inputCtrl.setValidators([Validators.required])
  } else  {
    this.inputCtrl.setValidators(null)
  }   
  this.inputCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

This is just a suggestion and present a option that I would personally prefer.

But if you prefer the custom validator, then go ahead with that (Amit's answer), just adding the `updateValueAndValidity` like suggested.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1oCtvJR8i51mT8DxlhT?p=preview)**

Comment: I helped him in the chat via plunks and such, that's eventually what we did, but we skipped setting and clearing the validators altogether, disabling and enabling the control ended up being a more suitable solution since it skipped validation for that field entirely anyway.

Comment: Best solution ;)